# search display controller issue on ios7

Tags: ios, ipad, uisearchbar, ios7

It's only happened on iPad,not in iPhone.

I have a search display controller in my listview, under a titlebar(not navigation bar). 
It can be displayed correctly, even I don't set self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone.

The issue is:
When I click in the text field of the searchbar, and then click someplace else to hide the keyboard and end the text input, the searchbar will be shown at the top-left corner of the screen. 
p.s.My listview is in the middle of the screen.

In one of my modal view, the search bar is under a navigation bar, there is no such issue. But I must set `self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone` to show the search bar.

Could you give me a hand please?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: IOS 7 is still under NDA, please use deforms.apple.com for these questions until it gets released.

Comment: @Eric, OK, thanks. I've posted there.